# Deprecated: Implicit conversion from float

Tags: php, xampp, laragon

Bueno tengo un sistema de asistencia echo en php que por parte de las funcionalidades (control de asistencia y generar pdfs) trabaja muy bien , todo el sistema para simular localmente utilice xampp , todo perfecto me funciona en las tres versiones (8.0.28, 8.1.17 & 8.2.4) y sus respectivas versiones de php.
Entonces opte por laragon como nuevo servicio web local , todo el funcionamiento trabaja muy bien pero por parte de generar los pdfs  me manda este error:
[image: error tcpdf]

Tengo la ultima version de laragon y la version de php 8.1.10
Utilizo TCPDF para generar los pdfs

Comment: Hola Jean, ¿que versión de TCPDF estas usando?

Comment: a partir de la version 8.1, se lanza un "deprecated" cuando se hace una conversion directa de un float a un int. probablemente en las lineas 4280 y 4281 hay una conversion directa, sin utilizar funciones como ceil(), o un cast directo. tiene pinta de ser por la version de tcpdf, que sea un poco antigua.

Answer (score 1):

### Causa del problema

Desde PHP 8 la conversión implícitamente incompatible de `float` a `int` está obsoleta.

[En php.watch viene explicado el motivo](https://php.watch/versions/8.1/deprecate-implicit-conversion-incompatible-float-string):

> Convertir un número flotante en un número entero a menudo implica
> perder el valor fraccionario del número flotante. Por ejemplo,
> **`6.8`**, un número flotante, será **`6`** cuando se convierta a un número entero. En lenguajes de programación de tipo dinámico como PHP,
> a veces esta conversión es involuntaria y no deseada.
>
> PHP está mejorando constantemente las reglas de su tipo dinámico,
> obligando a las reglas a ser más predecibles e intuitivas. PHP 8.0
> tiene mejoras como la conversión de flotante a cadena independiente de
> la configuración regional y mejoras en la comparación de cadenas
> numéricas.
>
> Desde PHP 8.1, se emite un aviso de obsolescencia cuando un valor
> flotante se fuerza implícitamente a un valor entero y se pierde el
> valor fraccionario en el proceso. Este aviso de obsolescencia no se
> emite cuando un valor flotante se convierte explícitamente en un
> número entero.
>
> El comportamiento de los tipos estrictos no ha cambiado. Cuando la
> escritura estricta está habilitada, PHP continúa lanzando una
> excepción `TypeError` en cada coerción de tipo implícita. Además, la
> conversión explícita a números enteros `((int) $floatNum)` o y las
> funciones `floatval` no se ven afectadas.
>
> Los avisos de obsolescencia se emiten cuando PHP implícitamente fuerza
> un valor flotante a un valor entero.

### Solución

Dado que es un problema generado por la librería TCPDF, lo que debes hacer es actualizar tu versión de dicha librería. El problema es conocido, fue reportado hace más de un año y corregido en junio de 2022 en el [pull #524](https://github.com/tecnickcom/TCPDF/pull/524). Con una versión actualizada de TCPDF este problema debería desaparecer.